# How to select distinct? not select duplicated row

Tags: oracle, query, greatest-n-per-group

I have 2 table

```
select DISTINCT (B.MAIN_ID), A.NAME,  A.NAME_ID, A.CREATED_DATE 
 from FAMILY A, ADDRESS B where B.F_ID = A.N_ID
```

result:

```
MAIN_ID   |  Name     |  NAME_ID | CREATED_DATE 
100       |  Erica    |  254     | 20190808-01:02:01
100       |  Erica    |  245     | 20190808-00:01:01
300       |  Eden     |  331     | 20190808-00:03:34
```

I want to be remove duplicated rows 'MAIN_ID' by created date, I need last created record. How can I do this? thanks

```
MAIN_ID   |  Name     |  NAME_ID | CREATED_DATE 
100       |  Erica    |  254     | 20190808-01:02:01
300       |  Eden     |  331     | 20190808-00:03:34
```

Comment: Which one of Erica's rows do you remove - what is the removal criterion? p.s. welcome to the forum! :-)

Comment: Why is the value 254?

Comment: Show source data which produces this output for this query.

Comment: 254 is the last created date

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: "Top N Row"  - the solution can be different depending on which version of Oracle you are using.  Please tag your question with the appropriate version.

Comment: I am using Oracle 12c

Comment: `distinct` is **NOT** a function. It always applies to all columns in the select list. Enclosing one column in parentheses won't change a thing. `distinct (a),b,c` is exactly the same thing as `distinct a,(b),c` or `distinct a,b,(c)`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Surely it is a function? One that acts on all of the fields in the query instead of just one?

Comment: @Vérace: not, it's not a function. It has no arguments and it has no return value. It's an operator. The parentheses around the columns are completely useless and have no influence on the working of the DISTINCT operator

Comment: @Solution - [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=4fec30e4248999a6ab3ec3b88b31e3d8)'s a subquery solution. You might want to test to see which works better for you. Of course, `derived_table` will add another layer... Assumes `name_id` is unique!

Comment: @Vérace did you check the answer's query?
Which one to be faster do you think? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` ranking function and a subquery (derived table or CTE):

```
WITH
  cte AS
  ( SELECT
      B.MAIN_ID, A.NAME, A.NAME_ID, A.CREATED_DATE,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY B.MAIN_ID
                         ORDER BY A.CREATED_DATE DESC)
        AS RN
    FROM
      FAMILY A JOIN ADDRESS B ON B.F_ID = A.N_ID
  )
SELECT MAIN_ID, NAME, NAME_ID, CREATED_DATE
FROM cte
WHERE RN = 1 ;
```